# Hair particles render a lot differently then in the render preview

Tags: rendering, particles, hair

I set Hair Number 6000 and the Children Render Amount 500, but the hair in the render view port is much less than it suppose to be.

[Blender project file](https://we.tl/t-EWs5whApoG)

In the solid mode the amount of hair looks right
[image: In the solid mode the amount of hair looks right]

In the render preview the hair is much less
[image: In the render preview the hair is much less]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Display Amount** control (Particle System > Children) affects how many hair instances are visible in the 3D viewport regardless of which mode the viewport is in, so even though you do have the children **Render Amount** set to 500, you currently have it set so that only 50 of them will appear in the viewport. When you increase **Display Amount** to 500, all of the child hair instances will render in the viewport and it will look more like what you are expecting (see below). [image: Full hair render]

However, rendering all children (especially 500 per each of 6,000 hairs for 3,000,000 total) will severely impact performance, so it's probably best that you leave the **Display Amount** substantially smaller than the render value (around 50 is what you had it at previously).

Leaving it at this value does not affect what the actual render output will look like, since at that point Blender will render all of the hairs. The image below is the render result with the settings exactly how you had them before (Display Amount = 50, Render Amount = 500), and it looks like what you're expecting. [image: Final render, settings unchanged.]

Comment: I see, thank you so much for detailed explanation!